# Many bugs and errors in 2SXC installation

Tags: installation, dotnetnuke, 2sxc

Many bugs and errors in 2SXC installation
**Can someone please give me some help?**
This is supposed to be trivially easy.
I have spent 7 hours on this and got nowhere.

In deploying the module on new DNN install :
DNN PLATFORM
v. 09.02.01 (533)

1. Install 2SXC into the DNN - Successful
2. Deploy Content Module on to empty page: Successful
3. Click circular icon.  Popup appears requiring Auto Configure button to be clicked.
   [Auto-Configure Content for 2sxc 11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VrMir.jpg)
   Dialog Text:-
   Auto-Configure Content for 2sxc 11? (Yes, I do)
   install recommended content package? (Yes, I do)

Popup: Do you want to install these packages? (Yes, I do)
- Default content for 2SXC11
It takes about 10 seconds per package. Don't re-load the page while it is installing.
I click OK
1 second later
Popup: An Error occurred.
[An Error Occurred](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOuUY.jpg)
Spinner rotates ad infinitum

Try the help page:  It says:-
"Run Auto-Configure and confirm the "are you sure" question, then wait a few seconds. Once you see the confirmation, everything worked". (Oh, No.  It certainly did not!)
Installing default content templates
An error occurred.

Looked up the Wiki
Tried to upload the Content Templates .zip file into a Content Module Admin/App. An Error Occurred on the upload.  Instruction says: See below for error.  (There was nothing below).

Any advice welcome!

Comment: What version of 2sxc did you install to start?

Comment: Also, why is your DNN version so old?

Comment: I uploaded the version of DNN which is provided by my provider ResellerChoice.
Next Action: I'll go to GitHub and get the latest update.

Comment: I Installed 2SXC 11.11.04 which is the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe should be really easy - I agree.

My guess is that something has gone wrong in a way that's hard to spot. Maybe an installation once got interrupted or something like that. It should be easy, so I really suggest one of the following options:

1. Quickly replay the same scenario with a blank DNN to experience how it should work, and to ensure that your PC isn't doing something funny (for example, the file is downloaded by the DNN server, and if your PCs firewall would prevent the IIS from getting files, this would fail).
2. If that worked, probably just uninstall 2sxc completely and also uninstall the DB (that doesn't happen automatically, because you may just uninstall and want to keep the data) - use https://azing.org/2sxc/l/Kf5yDYQq/uninstall-2sxc - then try again
3. Ask a friend to play this through once with you

Comment: Many thanks iJungleBoy!
I've run the scripts. Tables and SPs gone.
Now I'm going to upgrade to latest DNN
I hope that will simplify the problem.
Once I feel like I can control a demo site, we can take it from there perhaps.

Comment: I did a clean install of DNN
DNN PLATFORM
v. 09.09.00 (0)
I installed 2sic_2SexyContent_11.11.04_Install
I deployed the Module on an empty page.
An "Error" showed up on the floating module box.  It cleared when its update completed.
I deployed the Content Module on to the page OK
I clicked the round Icon of the module and was presented with the now-familiar Auto-Configure dialog.
I clicked the Install Content Package Blue button.
***The process failed with the "An Error Occurred" popup***

Sorry.  This software is not meeting my expectations.  It is failing at the first test.

Comment: If you try again, please use DNN v9.08.01.

Comment: Sorry for the problems Dave - There are somewhere between 10'000 and 25'000 installations using 2sxc and I hadn't heard of the issue you're describing, so I cannot really help. sorry.

Answer (score 0):

We just installed 2sxc on our development site, I’m super hopeful about it working - especially its ability to generate a json / json api. But! Today I used the Evoq page settings to delete “Content” instances on a test page - after that the “Add Module” to add a new “Content” instance fails - 2sxc’s javascript fails. Mysterious why just removing then trying to add “Content” instances would break 2sxc.

Comment: Best start a new thread and provide more infos, exact error messages etc.

Comment: hi daniel, stackoverflow won’t let me ask new questions. the issue occurs directly following clicking add module > 2sxc content. nothing appears in the gui and chrome’s inspector shows js issues. i’m also wondering if in our dnn layout ascx files can i somehow blacklist specific content panes from 2sxc? e.g., we never want to use 2sxc in our footer content pane.

Comment: Based on this info I couldn't give any guidance, sorry. Best ask a new question (I've never heard of SO blocking new questions...)